# Получить ключ по значению в python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть словарь словарей:

```py
cities = {  'Россия': ['Москва', 'Санкт-Петербург', 'Ростов-на-Дону', 'Казань'],
            'Германия': ['Берлин', 'Дюссельдорф', 'Дрезден', 'Кельн'], 
            'Франция': ['Марсель', 'Ницца', 'Лион'], 
            'Великобритания': ['Лондон', 'Глазго']}
```

Как по значению словаря получить на вывод ключ? (например, пишу Лондон, а принт выводит Великобританию)

Answer (score 0):

```py
cities = {  'Россия': ['Москва', 'Санкт-Петербург', 'Ростов-на-Дону', 'Казань'],
            'Германия': ['Берлин', 'Дюссельдорф', 'Дрезден', 'Кельн'], 
            'Франция': ['Марсель', 'Ницца', 'Лион'], 
            'Великобритания': ['Лондон', 'Глазго']}
city = input()
for country in cities:
    if city in cities[country]:
        print(f'{country} {len(cities[country])}')
```